# Geoserver tile caching

Tags: geoserver, layers

i have a problem with "tile layers". i want to display my layers in tile layers but i always have a blank page. i'm already displaying them in the "Preview layer" with openlayers and it worked. i don't know where is exactly the problem. i'm just a beginner in geoserver so if you have some useful tutoriel it will be great
thanks guys

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  It is usually the clearest Questions that describe exactly what has already been tried (by listing those steps) that tend to get Answer-ed the quickest.  I recommend that you use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with more details like your GeoServer version, your steps, which steps work as expected and which don't, etc.

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html

Answer (score 1):

Usually blank page happens because of wrong "Bounding Box".
Try to generate or type them manually on the layer (or group) first editors tab - "Data".

[image]